# How to get SwiftUI Text to clip instead of truncate with dots (...)

Tags: ios, swiftui

In a SwiftUI view, I have several `Text` elements in a `HStack`. Depending on the user input there will not be horizontal room to show all of the texts. The `HStack` does it job fine by ensuring all of the `Text` elements get equal widths and the strings are truncated. This is all as expected and as it should be.

The problem is that all the strings are truncated with a "..." in the end whereas I want the behaviour of `UILabel.lineBreakMode = .byClipping`, that is the string should simply be cut off at the edge of the `Text` element.

How do I achieve this?

Edit for more details on what I want:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextClipPoC: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            textElm
            textElm
            textElm
            textElm
        }
    }

    var textElm: some View {
        Text("abcdefghijklmn")
            .padding(.all, 3)
            .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}

struct TextClipPoC_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextClipPoC()
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 320, height: 40))
    }
}
```

gives this output:
[image: Default truncating behaviour]

I want the exact same output as above, except instead of "..." I want the text to just clip.

If I just add `.fixedSize()` to the `HStack` (or to the `Text` elements), as suggested in a solution, I get this result:
[image: With fixed with]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution is to overlay two instances of the same `Text`, one fixed size and one normal, let the normal one decide the size and hide it and then have the fixed size one clipped.

Can be done with a `ViewModfier`:

```
struct FixedClipped: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            content.hidden().layoutPriority(1)
            content.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
        }
        .clipped()
    }
}

extension View {
    func fixedClipped() -> some View {
        self.modifier(FixedClipped())
    }
}
```

and then used like this:

```
struct TextClipPoC: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            textElm
            textElm
            textElm
        }
    }

    var textElm: some View {
        Text("abcdefghijklmn")
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 3)
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .fixedClipped()
    }
}

struct TextClipPoC_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextClipPoC()
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 320, height: 40))
    }
}
```

This produces this result:
[image: Clipped text]

Answer (score 3):

To avoid truncation it needs to use fixed size, like

```
HStack {

   ... your text items here     

}
.fixedSize()
```

everything else depends on context of usage and will require `.clipped` at some upper container.

Other possible solution is to use deactivated `ScrollView`, like

```
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    HStack {

       ... your text items here     

    }
}.disabled(true)
```

Comment: I know I marked this as accepted, but I do not seem to be able to get the desired result. I have edited my question to clarify.